# Ошибка при запуске исполняемого файла (exe)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

Создал маленький проект на Qt в Clion, компилится, работает. При попытке запустить .exe файл выдает ошибку и просит библиотеки:

> libstdc++-6.dll  , libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал закинуть эти библиотеку руами, выдает другую ошибку: 0xc000007b.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cmake файл :

Не получилось корректно вставить сюда код, поэтому ссылка на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Q62BrQUj)

Comment: скорее всего Вы скопировали не те библиотеки. например, 32битные вместо 64.

Comment: Действительно, помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/592311)

Comment: Спасибо, учту ваше замечание